# follow vs following

Tags: tenses, verb-agreement

I have two simple questions:
In the sentence:

> "There is no greater thing to do than follow your passions in a way that serves the world and you"

1. Why should we say "follow" and not "following"?
2. As it says "passions" why does "serve" have an "s"?

Comment: There is no accounting for style.

Comment: It sounds as if you may be learning English.  If so, it may be better to ask this Q. on our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The choice between *follow* and *following* is subjective. Either could be used and be correct.

Although if *following* were used, the sentence would need to be rephrased in order to drop *to be*:

> There is no greater thing than following your passions in a way that serves the world and you.

---

The conjugation of *to serve* has nothing to with *passions*.

The following subject is what determines the singularity or plurality of the verb:

> in **a way** that **serves**
>   in **ways** that **serve**

Answer (score 0):

In comparatives like greater...than, the nature of the word after 'greater' and 'than' should be similar.
For example, "Better live than die"; not Better you live than dying.

The saying is "Better a living beggar than a buried emperor"

Here, it is wrong to say, 'Better live a beggar than a buried emperor."

Comment: For more precise parallelism oughtn't your second example be *Better a live beggar than a buried emperor* ?

Comment: "Better a living beggar than a buried emperor." Jean de la Fontaine.  I wish I could, but I am sure I can't, because it is a popular saying.

Answer (score 0):

"That serves the world and you" is a restrictive relative clause with "that" being the relative pronoun representing "the way," which is singular. "Serves" agrees with "that," because "that" is a stand-in for "the way."

Both follow and following work fine. What's interesting is that "follow' is an infinitive that has dropped its "to," which accords with the following

An infinitive can also lose its to when it is the second (or third, fourth, etc.) item in a series. For a series of infinitives, you need only the first to. The rest are unnecessary. http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitive.htm